# How do I put my flex box below to two flex boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new Flex in HTML.

So my question is I have three div's in my flex-container. But requirement is I want the third div to be below the one and second divs. Since I'm using flex-container with `display: flex`. Those three div's are getting accommodated in the same row itself.

Could someone help me.

```css
.flex-container-site-footer {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.One {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 12;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 12;
}

.three {
  background-color: black;
  flex-grow: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-site-footer">
  <div class="box One">
    <p>Box 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box two">
    <p>Box 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box three">
    <p>Box 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/j4z1esnw/)

Answer (score 2):

This will do. The `flex` shorthand is used for (in order):

- `flex-grow`,
- `flex-shrink`
- `flex-basis`.

Don't forget to [`autoprefix`](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

```css
.flex-container-site-footer{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex-container-site-footer > * {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.box{
  height:100px;
}
.One{
  background-color: blue;
}

.two{
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three{
  background-color: black;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-site-footer">
    <div class="box One">
        <p>Box 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box two">
        <p>Box 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box three">
        <p>Box 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need `max-width` and with a simple `flex-grow: 1`, you can simplify the code: https://jsfiddle.net/7bzb8btc/

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelB. I know the standard doesn't require it, but it's something I use whenever it doesn't break anything. I had recently a case involving margins and calc() on growing flex items in an App that had to cover Android 4.2 browser and the only workaround I found was using `max-width`. I since tend to add it with this thought in mind: *"will it hurt?"*. If not, I type it. But I agree, in here it qualifies as bloat.